Xquery expect return found ;
When I run my current XHTML page, I get the following error:


Retrieved_Data <?xml version="1.0" ?><exception><path>/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve.xq</path><message>exerr:ERROR org.exist.xquery.XPathException: err:XPST0003 expecting &quot;return&quot;, found ';' [at line 4, column 79]</message></exception>



Here is my XHTML code:


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
         <title>SVG_Bezier_Curve</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve.css"/>
          <script language="javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve_2.js">
          
          </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <input type="text" id="My_Text" value="I was here."/>
         <input type="button" onclick="Setup2()"/>
         <input type="button" onclick="Setup()"/>
         <p id="My_Paragraph"/>
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="My_SVG" height="500" width="500">
         <path id="Bezier_Curve_1"/>
         <path id="Bezier_Curve_2" d="M 300, 200 A 50, 50 0,0,1 400,200" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none">
</path>
    </svg>
    </body>
</html>



Here is my Javascript code:


function Setup() {
    var Bezier_Curve_Identification;
    var Attribute_Name;
    var Attribute_Name_2;
    var Coordinate;
    var My_Properties;
    
    document.getElementById("My_Text").value = "My Setup.";
    Attribute_Name = "d";
    Attribute_Name_2 = "style";
    My_Properties = "stroke: blue; stroke-width: 3; fill: none;";
    Coordinate = "M 300 200 A 20 20 0 0 0 400 200";
    Bezier_Curve_Identification = document.getElementById('Bezier_Curve_1');
    Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Attribute_Name, Coordinate);
    Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Attribute_Name_2, My_Properties);
    
  
}
function Setup2() {
    
    var SVG_Data;
    var Retrieved_Data;
    
    SVG_Data = new XMLHttpRequest();
          SVG_Data.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve.xq", true);
          SVG_Data.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (SVG_Data.readyState == 4) {
              Retrieved_Data = SVG_Data.responseText;
              document.getElementById("My_Text").value = "Retrieved_Data " + Retrieved_Data;}
          };
              
    SVG_Data.send();}  



Here is my XML:
<SVG_Data_Collection xmlns="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com SVG_Bezier_Curve_Data_Schema.xsd">
     <Bezier_Curve_1>
         <Main_Attribute>d</Main_Attribute>
         <Initial_Attribute>M</Initial_Attribute>
         <Coordinate_Start>300 200</Coordinate_Start>
         <Arc_Attribute>A</Arc_Attribute>
         <Bezier_Arc>20 20 0 0 0</Bezier_Arc>
         <Terminal_Coordinate>400 200</Terminal_Coordinate>
         <Style_Attribute>style</Style_Attribute>
         <Style_Color>stroke: red;</Style_Color>
         <Style_Width>stroke-width: 3;</Style_Width>
         <Style_Fill>fill: none;</Style_Fill>
     </Bezier_Curve_1>
     <Bezier_Curve_2>
        <Main_Attribute>d</Main_Attribute>
         <Initial_Attribute>M</Initial_Attribute>
         <Coordinate_Start>300 200</Coordinate_Start>
         <Arc_Attribute>A</Arc_Attribute>
         <Bezier_Arc>20 20 0 0 0</Bezier_Arc>
         <Terminal_Coordinate>400 200</Terminal_Coordinate>
         <Style_Attribute>style</Style_Attribute>
         <Style_Color>stroke: blue;</Style_Color>
         <Style_Width>stroke-width: 3;</Style_Width>
         <Style_Fill>fill: none;</Style_Fill>
     </Bezier_Curve_2>
</SVG_Data_Collection>


xquery version "3.0";
declare default element namespace "http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com"
declare option exist:serialize "method=text media-type=text/plain"
let $header-addition := response:set-header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
let $doc := doc("SVG_Bezier_Curve_Data.xml")/SVG_Data_Collection/Bezier_Curve_1
let $First_Data_Name := $doc/Main_Attribute
let $Data := concat($First_Data_Name, "*")
let $Second_Data_Name := $doc/Initial_Attribute
let $Data := concat($Data, $Second_Data_Name, "-")
let $Third_Data_Name := $doc/Coordinate_Start;
let $Data := concat($Data, $Third_Data_Name, "-")
let $Fourth_Data_Name := $doc/Arc_Attribute
let $Data := concat($Data, $Fourth_Data_Name, "-")
let $Fifth_Data_Name := $doc/Bezier_Arc
let $Data := concat($Data, $Fifth_Data_Name, "-")
let $Sixth_Data_Name := $doc/Terminal_Coordinate
let $Data := concat($Data, $Sixth_Data_Name)
return $Data

I would love to add my XQuery code, but this box won't let me.  I have a photo of my code, but you won't let me post the photo without copying and pasting the code.  How can I give you the code when this box won't let me give you the code?

Just curious: where does this SVG/XML description scheme come from? Is it needed for a graphic application? Just asking because it seems overly complicated to store and retrieve SVG data in/from a database. Specifying every path data command with a explicit command type (arc, bezier etc) and splitting the path data in main values and terminal coordinates appears quite complicated. In other words: If you can define the schema yourself you may simplify it e.g bya usung a single pathdata property like <Path_Data>M 375 200 A50 50 0 0 1 </Path_Data> that could directly be rendered in SVG

I'm trying to create two SVG Bezier curves that are exactly the same size.  Having equally sized Bezier curves would be useful if you are drawing things like soup cans or the body of an automobile.  As for the XML....well....I don't want to sift through hundreds of lines of XHTML or SVG code to find a specific path command and alter it's coordinates.  So storing the coordinates in XML would be a faster way to find specifically what I'm looking for.

You need to terminate declarations with a semicolon i.e. try
declare default element namespace "http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com";
declare option exist:serialize "method=text media-type=text/plain";


Yes, but it's hard to see how this explains the error message. I suspect it comes from som different code from that shown.

@MichaelKay, yes, it seems you are right that the error message can't be caused by a missing semicolon. Let's wait whether adding the semicolons helps speedlearner to identify the other errors.

Thanks for all your assistance.  I spent several hours examining each line of my code and I tested each line using the document.getElementById command.  Through this command I discovered that I referenced several incorrect documents.  You will notice this in the xml document.  Carefully examine the $doc variable to see the before and after.  I corrected several errors and for the most part my code actually works.  Here is my corrected code starting with the HTML:
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     <title>SVG_Bezier_Curve</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve.css"/>
      <script language="javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve_2.js">
      
      </script>
</head>
<body onload = "Setup()">
     <input type="button" id="Bezier_Curve_Button" onclick="Setup2()" value="Click Me!" position = "absolute" top = "100px"/>
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="My_SVG" position = "absolute" top = "200px" height="500px" width="600px">
     <path id="Bezier_Curve_1"/>
     <path id="Bezier_Curve_2"/>
     </svg>
</body>

Here is my Javascript:
    function Setup() {
    var Bezier_Curve_Identification;
    var Attribute_Name;
    var Attribute_Name_2;
    var Coordinate;
    var My_Properties;
    var Button_Identification;
    
    
    
    Attribute_Name = "d";
    Attribute_Name_2 = "style";
    My_Properties = "stroke: blue; stroke-width: 3; fill: none;";
    Coordinate = "M 375 200 A 50 50 0 0 1 475 200";
    Button_Identification = document.getElementById('Bezier_Curve_Button');
    Button_Identification.setAttribute = ("style", "top: 100px; height: 200px;");
    Bezier_Curve_Identification = document.getElementById('Bezier_Curve_1');
    Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Attribute_Name, Coordinate);
    Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Attribute_Name_2, My_Properties);
    
    
  
}

function Setup2() {
    
    var SVG_Data;
    var Retrieved_Data;
    var Bezier_Curve_1;
    var Bezier_Curve_2;
    var Counter;
    var Coordinate_Attribute;
    var Coordinate;
    var Style_Attribute;
    var Style_Details;
    var Bezier_Curve_Identification;
    
    SVG_Data = new XMLHttpRequest();
          SVG_Data.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve.xq", true);
          SVG_Data.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (SVG_Data.readyState == 4) {
              Retrieved_Data = SVG_Data.responseText;
              Retrieved_Data = Retrieved_Data.split("/");
              Counter = 0;
              Bezier_Curve_1 = Retrieved_Data[Counter];
              Counter = Counter + 1;
              Bezier_Curve_2 = Retrieved_Data[Counter];}
              Bezier_Curve_1 = Bezier_Curve_1.split("*");
              Counter = 0;
              Coordinate_Attribute = Bezier_Curve_1[Counter];
              Counter = Counter + 1;
              Coordinate = Bezier_Curve_1[Counter];
              Counter = Counter + 1;
              Style_Attribute = Bezier_Curve_1[Counter];
              Counter = Counter + 1;
              Style_Details = Bezier_Curve_1[Counter];
              Bezier_Curve_Identification = document.getElementById('Bezier_Curve_1');
              Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Coordinate_Attribute, Coordinate);
              Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Style_Attribute, Style_Details);
              Bezier_Curve_2 = Bezier_Curve_2.split("*");
              Counter = 0;
              Coordinate_Attribute = Bezier_Curve_2[Counter];
              Counter = Counter + 1;
              Coordinate = Bezier_Curve_2[Counter];
              Counter = Counter + 1;
              Style_Attribute = Bezier_Curve_2[Counter];
              Counter = Counter + 1;
              Style_Details = Bezier_Curve_2[Counter];
              Bezier_Curve_Identification = document.getElementById('Bezier_Curve_2');
              Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Coordinate_Attribute, Coordinate);
              Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Style_Attribute, Style_Details);
              
              };

SVG_Data.send();}

Here is my XML:
    <SVG_Data_Collection xmlns="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com SVG_Bezier_Curve_Data_Schema.xsd">
    <Bezier_Curve_1>
        <Main_Attribute>d</Main_Attribute>
        <Initial_Attribute>M </Initial_Attribute>
        <Coordinate_Start>375 200 </Coordinate_Start>
        <Arc_Attribute>A </Arc_Attribute>
        <Bezier_Arc>50 50 0 0 1  </Bezier_Arc>
        <Terminal_Coordinate>475 200</Terminal_Coordinate>
        <Style_Attribute>style</Style_Attribute>
        <Style_Color>stroke: red; </Style_Color>
        <Style_Width>stroke-width: 3; </Style_Width>
        <Style_Fill>fill: none;</Style_Fill>
    </Bezier_Curve_1>
    <Bezier_Curve_2>
        <Main_Attribute>/d</Main_Attribute>
         <Initial_Attribute>M</Initial_Attribute>
         <Coordinate_Start>375 200 </Coordinate_Start>
         <Arc_Attribute>A </Arc_Attribute>
         <Bezier_Arc>50 50 0 0 0 </Bezier_Arc>
         <Terminal_Coordinate>475 200</Terminal_Coordinate>
         <Style_Attribute>style</Style_Attribute>
         <Style_Color>stroke: blue;</Style_Color>
         <Style_Width>stroke-width: 3;</Style_Width>
         <Style_Fill>fill: none;</Style_Fill>
     </Bezier_Curve_2>
</SVG_Data_Collection>

And here is my Xquery:
    xquery version "3.0";
declare default element namespace "http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com";
declare option exist:serialize "method=text media-type=text/plain";
let $header-addition := response:set-header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
let $doc := doc("SVG_Bezier_Curve_Data.xml")/SVG_Data_Collection/Bezier_Curve_1
let $First_Data_Name := $doc/Main_Attribute
let $Data := concat($First_Data_Name, "*")
let $Second_Data_Name := $doc/Initial_Attribute
let $Data := concat($Data, $Second_Data_Name)
let $Third_Data_Name := $doc/Coordinate_Start
let $Data := concat($Data, $Third_Data_Name)
let $Fourth_Data_Name := $doc/Arc_Attribute
let $Data := concat($Data, $Fourth_Data_Name)
let $Fifth_Data_Name := $doc/Bezier_Arc
let $Data := concat($Data, $Fifth_Data_Name)
let $Sixth_Data_Name := $doc/Terminal_Coordinate
let $Data := concat($Data, $Sixth_Data_Name)
let $Seventh_Data_Name := $doc/Style_Attribute
let $Data := concat($Data, "*", $Seventh_Data_Name, "*")
let $Eighth_Data_Name := $doc/Style_Color
let $Data := concat($Data, $Eighth_Data_Name)
let $Ninth_Data_Name := $doc/Style_Width
let $Data := concat($Data, $Ninth_Data_Name)
let $Tenth_Data_Name := $doc/Style_Fill
let $Data := concat($Data, $Tenth_Data_Name)
let $doc := doc("SVG_Bezier_Curve_Data.xml")/SVG_Data_Collection/Bezier_Curve_2
let $First_Data_Name := $doc/Main_Attribute
let $Data2 := concat($First_Data_Name, "*")
let $Second_Data_Name := $doc/Initial_Attribute
let $Data2 := concat($Data2, $Second_Data_Name)
let $Third_Data_Name := $doc/Coordinate_Start
let $Data2 := concat($Data2, $Third_Data_Name)
let $Fourth_Data_Name := $doc/Arc_Attribute
let $Data2 := concat($Data2, $Fourth_Data_Name)
let $Fifth_Data_Name := $doc/Bezier_Arc
let $Data2 := concat($Data2, $Fifth_Data_Name)
let $Sixth_Data_Name := $doc/Terminal_Coordinate
let $Data2 := concat($Data2, $Sixth_Data_Name)
let $Seventh_Data_Name := $doc/Style_Attribute
let $Data2 := concat($Data2, "*", $Seventh_Data_Name, "*")
let $Eighth_Data_Name := $doc/Style_Color
let $Data2 := concat($Data2, $Eighth_Data_Name)
let $Ninth_Data_Name := $doc/Style_Width
let $Data2 := concat($Data2, $Ninth_Data_Name)
let $Tenth_Data_Name := $doc/Style_Fill
let $Data2 := concat($Data2, $Tenth_Data_Name)
return ($Data, $Data2)

